# How to select the latest dateTime of every week ? C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, datetime

I have to implement an algorithm who receive a list of DateTime and its recovers the latest DateTime of every week.

Example:

```
29/06/2016 -> Lastest date of the last week of the month
27/06/2016
24/06/2016 -> Lastest date of the before last week of the month
22/06/2016
21/06/2016
15/06/2016 -> Lastest of the third week
13/06/2016
...
```

Expected result

```
29/06/2016
24/06/2016
15/06/2016
```

I dont ask the code who done that but some directions or indication for resolve this problem.

Comment: What do you count as a "week"? Monday to Sunday? Sunday to Saturday? Something else?

Comment: In other words, are you need the end of every week to be returned?

Comment: @milletantoine in case of  `01/01/2015` and `01/01/2016` should both appear in your resultset or should `01/01/2016` be the only result, because both are week 1

Comment: If they are the lastest date of the week present in the list. the both should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: this answer assumes that you're interested in "natural" weeks, which don't really care about the year. For example, December 31st 2015 was a Thursday, and January 1st 2016 was a Friday - to my mind (and using the algorithm in this answer) those would count as being in the same week... the Monday before/on both days is the same, after all.

The simplest solution to this is probably to group by "start of week", then take the latest value within each group. Finding the start of the week is slightly awkward, and best done in a helper method:

```
var latestPerWeek = dates.GroupBy(StartOfWeek)
                         .Select(g => g.Max())
                         .ToList();

...

private static DateTime StartOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    date = date.Date; // Just remove any time parts...
    // 0=Sunday, 1=Monday... 6=Saturday
    int sundayToSaturdayDayOfWeek = (int) date.DayOfWeek;
    // 0=Monday, 1=Tuesday... 6=Sunday
    int mondayToSundayDayOfWeek = ((sundayToSaturdayDayOfWeek - 1) + 7) % 7;
    return date.AddDays(-mondayToSundayDayOfWeek);
}
```

Note that the .NET "week of year" handling is tempting to use, but basically doesn't handle this scenario. In Noda Time 2.0 this will be a lot simpler, but that isn't available yet...

Comment: I played a bit with your code, should be in case of `30.12.2015`, `31.12.2015`, `01.01.2016` be one or two valid results? I'd say `31.12.2015` is the latest of 53th week and `01.01.2016` is the latest of 1st week

Comment: @fubo: Well there's no indication that that's what the OP wants - I would personally assume that they'd want each week to consist of exactly 7 days, so treat 2016-01-01 and 2015-12-31 as being in the same week. I'll add that assumption into the answer though.

Answer (score 3):

**This works only for dates which are in the same year**

I would use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear` to determine the week number. After that you can `GroupBy` this number and order each group descending. Now you just have to pick the `First()` item of each week/ group

```
  List<DateTime> dtList = new List<DateTime>();
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016, 6,29));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016,6, 27));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016,6 ,24));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016,6,22 ));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016,6,21 ));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016,6, 15 ));
  dtList.Add(new DateTime( 2016, 6,13));

  List<DateTime> dtResult = dtList
      .GroupBy(x => CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday))
      .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y).First())
      .ToList();
```

Comment: That will fail if there are multiple years involved, as they'll be grouped by just week-of-year. Unfortunately .NET's week-year handling isn't terribly nice.

Comment: @JonSkeet so you would GroupBy Week + Year

Comment: No, you can't - because you really want to group by "week year" which isn't exposed, and weeks across year boundaries get split in .NET. Basically, the week-of-year handling in .NET just isn't up to the job here. See http://nodatime.org/unstable/userguide/weekyears.html for more on this.

Comment: That's irrelevant. Basically, two days in the same Monday-to-Sunday week can have different week numbers in .NET and be in different years... but you'd want them to group together. I've been doing a lot of work on this recently for Noda Time - please trust me when I say the BCL *really* isn't being helpful here.

Comment: If you want an example, consider 2014-12-29 (Monday) and 2015-01-01 (Thursday). They should be counted in the same week - they're not using your algorithm.

Comment: ok got it. i'll comment my answer to be valid only with dates within the same year